# Ansible loop break at condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need first item with a certain condition. For example, in this case, I want 'banana', the first item with state: true. Sample playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_fruit:
    fruits: [
      {state: false, fruit: apple},
      {state: true, fruit: banana},
      {state: true, fruit: orange},
      {state: false, fruit: pear}
    ]
  tasks:
    - name: get first fruit with state = true.
      set_fact:
        my_fruit: "{{ item.fruit }}"
      loop: "{{ fruits }}"
      when: 
        - item.state == true
        - my_fruit == ''

    - name: Check true fruit.
      debug:
        var: my_fruit
```

The output is:

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [get first fruit with state = true.] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': False, 'fruit': 'apple'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': True, 'fruit': 'banana'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': True, 'fruit': 'orange'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': False, 'fruit': 'pear'}) 

TASK [Check true fruit.] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_fruit": null
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

`my_fruit` result is null, if I skip `- my_fruit == ''` condition, the result is 'orange':

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [get first fruit with state = true.] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': False, 'fruit': 'apple'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'state': True, 'fruit': 'banana'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'state': True, 'fruit': 'orange'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': False, 'fruit': 'pear'}) 

TASK [Check true fruit.] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_fruit": "orange"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How can I do to get 'banana'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from the fact that you initialize the variable "my_fruit" to null and not as an empty string (your condition "`my_fruit == ''`" is testing either the variable is an empty string or not) that's why the playbook is skipping your whole list. I suggest that you initialize your variable to `my_fruit: ''` and it should work

```
TASK [get first fruit with state = true.] ****************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': False, 'fruit': 'apple'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'state': True, 'fruit': 'banana'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': True, 'fruit': 'orange'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'state': False, 'fruit': 'pear'}) 

TASK [Check true fruit.] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_fruit": "banana"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_fruit: "{{ (fruits|selectattr('state')|first).fruit }}"
```

Details:

- See [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr) *"If no test is specified, the attribute’s value will be evaluated as a boolean."*
- It's possible to use an index in the list, instead of the filter *`first`*

```yaml
        my_fruit: "{{ (fruits|selectattr('state')|list).0.fruit }}"
```